# Implement Branching strategy in DevOps for Multi-Tenant application

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch

I am new to DevOps, and i have a solution with Umbraco as CMS, Mobile App as front-end for the content added in CMS and .Net MVC web API to connect CMS with the Mobile App. I also have WebJobs and Microsoft flow for some scheduling tasks.

Now, I need to implement DevOps for my Multi Tenant Application, here is my scenario:

The solution will have one master application which will just serve as master list of features for admin to enable features while creating new community. Multiple communities having separate databases, each community has multiple features (Feature1, Feature2). There should be a way for developers to forward integrate and backward integrate the features.

After adding the feature to any community, It can have its own customizations in particular feature. In some scenarios developers also need to add these changes to the master or the sibling communities. I also have added the image for better understanding.

[image]

Now, i need help in creating the Branching Strategy for my solution that fulfills all above requirements and minimize the chances of conflicts while merging the branches all across. I have below options in my mind.

i) Should i consider each Feature as separate branch? If yes, how about managing the community specific changes done in any single community?

ii) Should i consider each community as separate branch? If yes, how do i separate out the feature code to be merged with the community branch?

iii) Should i consider shared code among all the communities? If yes, what about the community specific changes?

Everything is going to be on the fly once deployed (in code base using Visual Studio 2017). 
Which strategy i should go for? Or there is any better approach than these? How can i manage to resolve the merge conflicts if generated after the deployment ? Also, in DevOps Should i go for Git or TFS?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: This may be better placed on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. That aside, would it not be easier to have one application and have multiple deployments? Just give each feature a toggle and for each deployment you can have different features toggles turned on and off.

Git isn't really a great tool to use for managing feature adoption, it's for text file version management.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn, Thanks for the reply. As you said that Git isn't a really good tool for this, do you suggest TFS is a better option for DevOps and my requirements?

Comment: no I suggest you re-think your approach. Using any sort of version control for application feature flags is a bad idea. You should research feature flags (sometimes called Feature Toggles). Git, TFS, SVN, all of those will be painful to do this sort of development.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn, So you suggest not to dig into branches instead use Feature flags. As i am new to all this, can you give a hand to understand more on this? Any reference will also work. Thanks for the Help.

Comment: sure thing, I'll provide my response as an answer so I get more text formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think branches is the right approach to this. It seems like you want to deploy the same application just with different **configurations**. Configurations should be outside of the main code base in most instances.

Lets say you have an arbitrary application with 3 possible features:

1. Customisable avatars,
2. User notifications,
3. A public restful API (or graphql if that's your jam).

All of these features will be within the same codebase, they will all need to work together but they also may not all be features that each tenant wants.

*Note: in this case, "tenant" could be anything such as different countries for a SaaS like platform, or different companies if you're selling to businesses.*

Because all the features have to be able to work together anyway, you will want to keep the application as one cohesive piece. This means you have a single product / code base (perhaps split into microservices if that's what you want to do) but you might deploy it with different configurations.

You might deploy the product to a bank called TheBank with all 3 features turned on, you might also deploy to a smaller company called TheFlowerShop which only needs user notifications (plus the core offering). In this case, you will deploy the same code base but with some way of deciding if a feature should be usable. There are many ways of doing this, but usually they're all called "Feature Flags" or "Feature Toggles".

A feature flag, is essentially some sort of configuration that you can check at run-time to see how the application should act. Lets take the simple case, you might have a JSON configuration file for your service which looks something like this:

```
{
    "features": {
         { "name": "custom_avatars", "enabled": true }
         ....
    }
}
```

This can be setup when you deploy the application and will define what features are turned on or off, at run time you can read in this file and check to see if a feature is on. If the feature called "public_api" is disabled, then you won't allow users to generate tokens for that, and you won't allow HTTP calls from anything but itself. If the user notifications are turned off, then when a system event happens you won't dispatch the notification to the users email, you'll just ignore it.

This sort of configuration can sit in many different places, it could be next to your general configurations such as your database connection details or it could be a seperate file. It could also be run by a service that provides this functionality, there are a lot of feature toggle / feature flag applications out there that provide nice UI's for managing this.

The moment you start doing different branches of the application for different deployments you'll get into a huge mess. You're going to have to duplicate fixes and you'll basically be managing several diverging versions of the same code base which will eventually grow away from each other. At some point you might find fixes applied to one branch won't work on the other branch.

Stick with a single application, but make it configurable.

Comment: Thank you very much for long descriptive explanation. It is helping me a lot.
Let me know if "Stick with a single application, but make it configurable" rule is still applicable if my multiple tenant's has : 1. The tenant will not share the content expect some configuration
2. The tenant might have some extension to the base feature,i.e. some functions added/removed or twicked form a feature.
3. My solution is micro-service based architecture
4. The Data security measures are different per tenant
5. May be the deployment mode/environment is different, like some on cloud or on premise etc

Comment: I still think highly configurable is the best answer even with all these things. You might end up with a lot of configuration, but you'll save yourself a lot of time and will be able to fit many more needs if you have a lot of configuration over several seperate code branches. What happens if you want to mix-and-match various things in the future but they don't live on the same branches? I've worked for two companies now which take a configuration approach and it's always felt like a good decision, it just requires good documentation to be written sometimes.

Comment: @ Elliot Blackburn Thank You for all your help. I have one more concern for this approach. Is it better to maintain the feature flags in our application or should i go for any Third Party Feature Management tool ?

Comment: @Developer that's a business decision for you to make, it depends on the complexity of the application and how easily you want to be able to toggle them and all sorts. That's well outside the scope for this question and isn't a decision we can make for you.